# single String.split() call for splitting both CRLF and space

Tags: actionscript-3

How to use string.split() for both  CRLF and whitespace ?  Do I need regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately AS3 does not allow you to split after an array of chars, like the classic OO languages (C#, Java, C++).

You would have to use a RegExp for the second param of String.Split:

\n Matches a newline character.

\r Matches a return character.

\t Matches a tab character.

Comment: so what would be the whole regexp like split (a, "/\s+$/");

Comment: you can use groups and the OR operator: |

Answer (score 0):

```
text.split('\r\n').join('\r');<br/>
text.split('\r').join('\r\n');
```